# How does gulp treat the Promise of a then()?

Tags: javascript, promise, gulp, del

I have a strange behaviour using gulp as build tool. I got the following code from another question, which is meant for cleaning up build files before another run:

```
function clean() {
    var delResult = del(['build/**/*', 'dist/**/*']);
    return delResult.then(del(['build', 'dist']));
}

gulp.task('clean', clean);
```

Then I have my default task which includes the clean task in the rest of the build:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('doJsStuff, doCssStuff', 'doEvenMoreStuff'));
```

The problem is that gulp already continues with the build before the two del-operations have completed.
As I understand it `then` will return a promise and gulp should continue when that promise gets fulfilled. Of course the `then`-promise can not get fulfilled before the first `del`-promise does. So I guess it should work as expected but doesn't.
The behaviour is the same in gulp 3 and 4.

I am aware that I can do the same stuff using only one `del`-call:

```
function clean() {
    return del(['build/**', 'dist/**']);
}
```

That actually works and is a solution for my problem. Still I would like to understand, why the chained promises don't work. Can anybody tell me?

Comment: `.then()` accepts a function, not a `Promise`. Maybe you meant `return delResult.then(() => del(['build', 'dist']));`?

Comment: Ah, I see, of Course, `del(['build', 'dist'])` will be executed immediately not after the first `del` has finished, because I give the result of `del`to `then` and not the `del`-function itself. This obviously leads to undeterministic behaviour. Thanks! I would gladly accept your comment as the answer.